# Parsing error: Unexpected token stripe? slint

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, eslint, jslint

When I replace `functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {`  with `functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {` I end up getting the following error:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token stripeslint

I get this error for `strip.`

```
 const strip = require('stripe')('KeyString');
 
 exports.createConnectAccount = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {// functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    // Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
    // See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
 
    const account = await strip.accounts.create({ //get error here: strip
      type: 'express',
    });
 
    let refURL = account.refresh_url
    let retURL = account.return_url
 
    console.log("mi caca la caca 00>", account, retURL, refURL, account.uid, account.userId, account.userRef, account.user, account.id, account.ref, account.pushId, account.customer_id)
 
 });
```

**Packedge.json**

```
    {
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/logging": "^9.1.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0",
    "stripe": "^8.56.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: You need to use the `async` keyword when declaring the HTTPS Cloud Function. `functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {...}`. Also you should correctly terminate it, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I had tried that before, and although it seems workable, I get the following weird warning on code bellow: https://ibb.co/6w5JfBH Unexpected function expression.eslintprefer-arrow-callback

Comment: You need to use the promise version not the callback one.

Comment: Seems like this solved the issues, write it up as an answer so I'll accept. @RenaudTarnec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you need to adapt in your code:

1. Use the `async` keyword when declaring the HTTPS Cloud Function. `functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {...}`.
2. Correctly terminate your cloud function by using the promise version of the `create()` method. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions for more details on this key aspect.